# $\int_0^1 \log f(t)dt \le \int_0^1 \log g(t)dt$ implies $\int_0^1 \log (f(t)+1)dt \le \int_0^1 \log (g(t)+1)dt$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Assume that $f,g$ are decreasing positive functions on $(0,1)$.
If $\int_0^1 \log f(t)dt \le \int_0^1 \log g(t)dt$, then is it true that $\int_0^1 \log (f(t)+1)dt \le \int_0^1 \log (g(t)+1)dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $g(t)$ as $e-1$ and $f(t)$ as $e^{(1-t^2)^2}$.